# DRF Use serializer to validate body and serialize response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following view in django which signs in a user and sends back the response after the user data has been serialized using a serializer.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def sign_in(request):
    username = request.data['username']
    password = request.data['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        update_last_login(None, user)  # update the user's last login date
        serializer = UserSignInSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    return Response('Invalid login credentials', status=401)
```

What I don't like about this view is the way I extract the username and password directly from the body. I'd like to use the same serializer to check if the body is valid. Is this possible or do I have to create a new serializer just to validate requests? Here's the existing serializer:

```
class UserSignInSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username', 'profile']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`object level validation`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation) from django rest framework. Here is a nice code you can use from [**`django rest auth`**](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/serializers.py#L19). I am following it to give you an example here:

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'})

    def authenticate(self, **kwargs):
        return authenticate(self.context['request'], **kwargs)

    def _validate_username(self, username, password):
        user = None

        if username and password:
            user = self.authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        else:
            msg = _('Must include "username" and "password".')
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)

        return user

    def validate(self, attrs):
        username = attrs.get('username')
        password = attrs.get('password')
        user = self._validate_username(username, password)
        if user:
            if not user.is_active:
                msg = _('User account is disabled.')
                raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)
        else:
            msg = _('Unable to log in with provided credentials.')
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)

        attrs['user'] = user
        return attrs
```

And use this serializer in view:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def sign_in(request):
    serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
    if serializer.is_valid():
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        update_last_login(None, user)  # update the user's last login date
        u_serializer = UserSignInSerializer(user)
        return Response(u_serializer.data)

    return Response(serializer.errors, status=401)
```

Comment: So the answer is to just create a new serializer? Wouldn't this mean that I would have to create two serializers for each view I have? One for req and one for res?

Comment: You can make it in one serializer. But then you need to make first_name last name etc read only fields and password write only field. But IMHO in that way, code won't be clean, one serializer bearing all. But having two serializers with two different purpose seems nicer to me. In that way, you can keep login and user information different and change any one of them without affecting other

Comment: Also, what do you mean by `couldn't this mean that I would have to create two serializers for each view I have`?

Comment: your above view uses two serializers. I would probably have to do this with all my views if the req body contains different data than the response

Comment: Well, if the request and response is totally different then its better to have two serializers. But usually one serializer is used.  In this case, as I said before, you can fit them in one. But for cleaner code, I used two serializers.